# Create random lines inside a polygon

Tags: r, line

I want to create X random lines (not polylines) inside an area. I have managed to do so, however the output shapefile i get has only one linear object that includes all the random lines. I want X separate lines, but i have trouble getting them. I have implemented my code in R. Any suggestions?

```
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
d <- structure(list(x = c(0.08394638623612, 0.0758558910509947, 0.197213318827875, 
                          0.209349061605562, 0.268005151697721, 0.280140894475409, 0.08394638623612, 
                          0.08394638623612, 0.112263119384059, 0.120353614569184, 0.112263119384059, 
                          0.100127376606371, 0.090014257624964, 0.0920368814212453, 0.41767931262254, 
                          0.454086540955604, 0.454086540955604, 0.462177036140729, 0.504652135862637, 
                          0.520833126232887, 0.545104611788263, 0.551172483177108, 0.553195106973389, 
                          0.852543428823026, 0.959742490025936, 0.963787737618499, 0.907154271322622, 
                          0.909176895118903, 0.937493628266842, 0.955697242433374, 0.941538875859404, 
                          0.931425756877998, 0.927380509285435, 0.911199518915184, 0.899063776137496, 
                          0.0859690100324013, 0.08394638623612), y = c(0.0984799434209303, 
                                                                       0.184633290921423, 0.173297324145043, 0.218641191250565, 0.218641191250565, 
                                                                       0.352405599211856, 0.356939985922409, 0.522445100857566, 0.529246680923394, 
                                                                       0.547384227765603, 0.567788967963088, 0.579124934739469, 0.585926514805297, 
                                                                       0.789973916780149, 0.862524104148985, 0.837584977240947, 0.801309883556529, 
                                                                       0.767301983227388, 0.751431629740455, 0.762767596516835, 0.776370756648492, 
                                                                       0.833050590530395, 0.867058490859537, 0.871592877570089, 0.864791297504261, 
                                                                       0.497505973949529, 0.474834040396767, 0.440826140067625, 0.418154206514864, 
                                                                       0.418154206514864, 0.313863312172162, 0.273053831777192, 0.216373997895289, 
                                                                       0.184633290921423, 0.141556617171177, 0.0962127500656542, 0.0984799434209303
                          )), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, -37L), class = "data.frame")

## polygon

sp <- raster::spPolygons(cbind(d$x, d$y), attr = data.frame(p = 1))

pts <- spsample(sp, n = 500, type = "random")

l <- split(as.data.frame(coordinates(pts)), rep(seq(length(pts)/2), each = 2))

lp <- raster::spLines(lapply(l, as.matrix))
op <- par(bg = "black")
plot(sp, border = "yellow", lwd =2 )
plot(lp, add = TRUE, col = "yellow", lty = 2)
df<-SpatialLinesDataFrame(lp, data.frame(id=1:length(lp)))
writeOGR(df, dsn="c:/Ouputs" ,layer="synth_data",driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to construct multiple SpatialLines features with `spLines` from a set of matrices is something like:

```
ML = spLines(m1, m2, m3, m4, m5)
```

Since you have a list you want to use `do.call`, which feeds the elements of a list to a function in the same way as above. For example, this is equivalent to that:

```
L = list(m1,m2,m3,m4,m5)
ML = do.call(spLines, L)
```

So in your case, after creating the list of data frames, `l`:

```
> l <- split(as.data.frame(coordinates(pts)), rep(seq(length(pts)/2), each = 2))
```

It should be a case of using `do.call` on the list of data frames converted to matrices, but this throws an error:

```
> lp = do.call(spLines,lapply(l, as.matrix))
Error in (function (x, ..., attr = NULL, crs = "")  : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Which I've tracked down to something odd in `spLines` that fails because of the names of the list items. Drop those names:

```
> names(l)=NULL
```

and it works:

```
> lp = do.call(spLines,lapply(l, as.matrix))
```

`lp` is now 250 separate features which you can combine with a 250 row data frame to create a SpatialLinesDataFrame with 250 features:

```
> lp
class       : SpatialLines 
features    : 250 
extent      : 0.07946532, 0.9612992, 0.1066574, 0.8623224  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : NA
```

Comment: Great answer! Wish there was a visualization with this